# Rendering canvas from Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, canvas

I have a chart in my current web app that I’ve implemented in canvas. I’d like this to work in IE8, but excanvas doesn’t seem to support translucency or composite operations. My fallback solution is to render a chart on the server as an image and send that out to IE8 instead of rendering it client-side.

I’d assumed there’d be a canvas gem that I could use with a direct port of my JS code to Ruby, but I can’t find anything. Has no-one done this? If not, what would people recommend? It’s not a particularly complex drawing, but I’d like to keep the amount of duplication to a minimum.

(It’s worth pointing out that I’ve considered using a headless Webkit to render and return a data URI, but I expect this would be fairly slow to spin up. Another possibility is to pre-render all the possible charts – somewhere around 120K of them – but that feels like a last resort!).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found such an implementation.

There is at least one [canvas implementation for node.js](https://github.com/learnboost/node-canvas). You could use it to write a small node program to generate the images using the exact same code you're using on the client. It wouldn't be the most efficient solution but I'd guess it'd be better than using PhantomJS or the like.

Comment: Apparently not out of the box, but the docs mention [some solutions](https://github.com/LearnBoost/node-canvas/wiki/Installation-Heroku)